# Translating strings in file to hexadecimal (Ruby) Part II

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I'm new to Ruby and trying to convert a text file containing DNA sequences into a hexadecimal output. I am currently using a hash to match strings with hex-values.

A sample input file might contain ctgcagccgc cgactgaaat. In that case, the output should be 79259 61E03.

What can I do to properly to hash the file to output the hash table key value from string to hexadecimal or another string value?

Below is what I have so far:

```
#dna_sequencing.rb

sequence_dna = {
  "aa" => 0, "ac" => 1, "ag" => 2, "at" => 3, "ca" => 4, "cc" => 5, 
  "cg" => 6, "ct" => 7, "ga" => 8, "gc" => 9, "gg" => 'A', 
  "gt" => 'B', "ta" => 'C', "tc" => 'D', "tg" => 'E', "tt" => 'F'
}
File.open("dna_sequences.txt") do |line|
    #puts line
    line.each do |fp|
        key, value = fp.chomp.split(" ")
        sequence_dna[key] = value
        #puts sequence_dna[key]
        puts sequence_dna
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'ctgcagccgc cgactgaaat'.gsub(/\w./, sequence_dna)
=> "79259 61E03"
```

Comment: This should be definitely marked as the best answer. `\S` is nifty :)

Comment: Actually I just realized I could've used `\w`. My thought process went like `[acgt]`→`[^ ]`→`\S`. Rather silly :-). I'll replace.

Answer (score 1):

```
input = 'ctgcagccgc cgactgaaat'
output =
  input.split.map do |s|
    s.chars.each_slice(2).map { |g| sequence_dna[g.join] }
  end.map(&:join).join(' ')
#⇒ "79259 61E03"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in any real-world DNA analysis you are going to be encountering large files, I would suggest a procedure that reads from one file and writes back out to another. This way you will have  no problems running short of memory.

The `sequence` method below handles file reads and writes. The `dna_to_hex` method does the comparison and substitution work on a line-by-line basis.

```
SEQUENCE_DNA = {
    'aa' => '0', 'ac' => '1', 'ag' => '2', 'at' => '3', 'ca' => '4', 'cc' => '5',
    'cg' => '6', 'ct' => '7', 'ga' => '8', 'gc' => '9', 'gg' => 'A',
    'gt' => 'B', 'ta' => 'C', 'tc' => 'D', 'tg' => 'E', 'tt' => 'F'
}

def sequence(input_file_name, output_file_name)
  File.open(output_file_name, 'w') do |output_file|
    File.open(input_file_name).each_line { |line| output_file.write(dna_to_hex(line)) }
  end
end

def dna_to_hex(line)
  line.gsub(/\S./, SEQUENCE_DNA)
end
```

You'll use it by passing the name of an input file and the name of an output file:

```
>> sequence('dna_sequences.txt', 'dna_output.txt')
```

Edit: I've borrowed the string substitution method from @StefanPochmann, as it seems to be the clear best choice for that piece of the problem.

Comment: Good practice would be to read/write stdin/stdout. You can connect those streams to files when you run the script.